# void(* resetDevice) (void) = 0; What kind of a function is this?

Tags: function, void

```
void(* resetDevice) (void) = 0;
```

This was a function declaration I stumbled upon, moreover no definition found later.
What kind of a function is this? What does it do? What does it return?

Comment: It would help to know what language this is. C?

Comment: It's C code running on an Arduino board.

Answer (score 1):

This is pointer to void function accepting no parameters. Pointer is named resetDevice and is initialized to null. Some library code later will initialize it to point to real function. You will be able to call it with

```
resetDevice();
```

Now, what will that function do exactly, I have no idea - it depends on your environment/libraries, which you have not specified. My guess would be it is Arduino, you can read bit more about it here

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=385427.0

Answer (score 0):

I use this piece of code to reset my Arduino board.
As I found it, it is not a really elegant method to reset the board, but it works.
If you call "resetDevice()" while it is pointing to address 0 (NULL), it will cause a runtime error or "null pointer exception" as the pointer is not pointing to a valid memory location containing a function. And that error causing a board reboot.